# Python: Why is my code for creating an upside-down right triangle not displaying the stars?

Tags: python

im trying to create an upside down triangle with this:

```
size = int(input("Enter the size of the upside-down right triangle: "))

m = 0
while size > 0:
    while m < size:
        print("*", end="")
        m = m + 1
    print()
    size = size - 1
```

but the output is only

```
****
```

the print prints out 4 stars at the top with lines on the bottom but the stars do not appear

Comment: You need to set `m` back to `0` each time through the main loop.

Comment: Move `m = 0` down 1 line.

Comment: Or get rid of it entirely and use `for _ in range(size):`

Answer (score 1):

You haven't reset the value of `m` to `0` inside the outer `while` loop. So `m` retains its value from the previous iteration, causing the inner loop to not execute since `m` is already greater than `size`.

```
size = int(input("Enter the size of the upside-down right triangle: "))

while size > 0:
    m = 0  # Reset m to 0 for each row
    while m < size:
        print("*", end="")
        m = m + 1
    print()
    size = size - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of m is never reset. Since you add 1 to m every time the nested loop executes, then m stays at the value of size once the loop is completed. You need to add a reset in line 4 (or before the nested loop) where m's value resets so it can run the loop again.